# How can I install vim in minimal version of  fedora?

Tags: linux, vim, fedora

I installed minimal version of fedora. Now how can I install vim in fedora. I have the packages for vim. But while I want to install it says A exception is occurred. Now I want to install vim directly from Internet.

Comment: This would be better on Superuser or unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: What exactly fails if you do "yum install vim-minimal"?

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember:

```
yum -i vim
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need `vim-enhanced` package if want build with all the bells and whistles or `vim-minimal` if you want to keep your system as small as possible.